# SalesForce SOQL join Leads to Contact

Tags: salesforce, soql, salesforce-service-cloud

I'm trying to query data out of SalesForce Lead using SOQL and JOIN and obtain contact information where for the Lead Created through the contacts object.
I'm not sure which objects to use how to go about doing it. 
Does anyone know of a detail schema of what can be used with SOQL relationship queries. 
I've tried some examples from the following links but don't know how to do the same with Leads, contacts:

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/05/basic-soql-relationship-queries.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all you didnt mention properly what you want

```
List<lead> info = [Select * from Lead where Id = 'Id name of that Particular record of lead'];

system.debug(info);
```

now you can see all information of that particular lead in logs.